# Loop through <div> elements using PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have a block of html in a string that is basically a list of divs... Each div has html inside that I want to parse seperately.

I am having trouble figuring out exactly how to loop over the initial divs.

Can anyone help?

An example of the html:

```
<div><!-- stuff in here --></div>
<div><!-- stuff in here --></div>
<div><!-- stuff in here --></div>
<div><!-- stuff in here --></div>
```

In this example I would expect the final code to loop round 4 times and provide me with the contents of each div

Comment: If you do things like that a lot, i suggest you look at phpQuery http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work (if the HTML is in an external file):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('test.html');
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $n) {
    echo $n->nodeValue;
}
```

And in case of a string containing the HTML, you could do:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<html><body><div>A</div><div>B</div><div>C</div><div>D</div></body></html>');
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $n) {
  echo $n->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

which would produce:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: With this, you just need to careful about divs within your divs.  Those will be iterated over as well.

Comment: It is an external file, I already seperate out the section I want using strpos and substr, can I do this on a HTML fragment?

Comment: John, I added a bit to your answer. Normally I would add it as a comment to your answer, but since it was more or less the same as what you yourself already answered, I edited it right away. Of course, if you object, feel free to remove it.

Comment: Can I make this intolerant to errors? I could paste (externally) the html im trying to parse?

Comment: @Bart K., additions and improvements are always welcome. :) 
@Chris, you can add error checking to this by verifying their is actually HTML in the string/file to be checked. You can also add HTML right into the loadHTML method just like Bart's example shows.

Answer (score 0):

If it's XHTML, you can use SimpleXML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xhtmlstring);
foreach ($xml->div as $d) {
   {
   //parsing
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried simple xml but it fails to load unfortunately, im not sure why!

Comment: Try this to output xml errors:
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0'><broken><xml></broken>");
if (!$sxe) {
    echo "Failed loading XML\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}