# Get text from HTML programmatically

Tags: html, web

At my job, I am occasionally tasked with entering data from an HTML page into an excel file manually. This usually details something like a course offering list where I have to get the title, degree type, link to the page, and other information. Is there a way I can programmatically handle this? I have beginner to intermediate programming skills in Java, Python, and PHP and I've got very solid foundations in Web Dev.

Conceptually from what I understand, I would have to loop to find certain text between tags/classes and then dump that into another text file? From there I'm pretty lost.

What should I do?

Comment: How hard have you looked? What have you tried so far? Is the HTML data in the same format/structure each time? You could try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089258/loop-through-div-elements-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, I would look into using **JavaScript** to get the values between the tags.

More specifically, you'd be interested in the `innerText` property of DOM elements:

`var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").innerText;`

That will store the text from the element whose ID is "myBtn" in the variable `x`.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp

Comment: That will store the text inside of the element whose *ID* is "myBtn" in the variable

Comment: Thanks for this. Helped me get to where I needed. You can see what I did and how I used your answer in a reply I made below.

Answer (score 0):

found what I was looking for thanks to some of the comments to this post. I've gone ahead and made a loop shown below:

```
var Array = [];
$('.class').each(function () {
    Array.push(this.innerHTML);
});
```